# Paypal IPN Verification Postback with HTTPS

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

According to new security requirements (2016, 2017 and 2018), it seems that HTTPS will be required for exchange between server and Paypal, during an "IPN". [This question is linked to this subject](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/6374) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759480/paypal-ipn-https-changes-2016).

**How should we adapt this PHP IPN code?**

```
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:80\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

...

fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
```

**Would replacing the two occurences of `www.paypal.com` by `https://www.paypal.com` be enough?**

Also, is the fact my shop website is not HTTPS a problem, will this connection be refused?

---

Here is part of the email received from Paypal:

[image]

---

**Edit (2018/06/22)**, here is the actual IPN code, after applying the accepted answer code. Strangely, I still get: "IPN Verification postback to HTTPS. Update needed: YES". So this means the following code is still not 100% compliant to HTTPS. Why?

```
<?php
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = trim(urlencode(stripslashes($value)));
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('tls://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
// and many more

if (!$fp)
{
  // HTTP ERROR
} else
{
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp))
  {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
    {
        // send email to customer, etc.
    }
  }
  fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: port would be 443, not 80.

Comment: Linked question: [Why does tlstest.paypal.com work from browser but not from my PHP code (useful for Paypal IPN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938090/why-does-tlstest-paypal-com-work-from-browser-but-not-from-my-php-code-useful-f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `hostname`
>
> If OpenSSL support is installed, you may prefix the `hostname` with either `ssl://` or `tls://` to use an SSL or TLS client connection over TCP/IP to connect to the remote host.
>
> http://www.php.net/fsockopen

The port would also need to change to `443`. So:

```
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
...
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
...
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
```

`https://` would not work because you're opening a *socket*, which is a low-level transport. HTTP is an application level protocol on top of that, which the socket doesn't know or care about. At the socket level it's a *TLS* connection.

> Also, is the fact my shop website is not HTTPS a problem, will this connection be refused?

What kind of connection a browser has to your server is irrelevant and nobody knows that. You're opening a socket from a PHP program to Paypal, you may as well be doing that directly from the command line without any "HTTP" connection involved at all.

Comment: A small note that the port doesn't *have* to be 443, and that server admins can set any port to being the secure port. (Although some who sets a custom secure port would, I hope, also be someone who realises this when reading a SO answer)

Comment: Yeah, if you're being told to use *HTTPS* without further details, it'd be pretty sadistic to use any port other than 443. :)

Comment: @Basj Just `Host: www.paypal.com:443`, if anything. `Host: www.paypal.com` by itself should probably do just fine, and completely omitting the header will probably do as well.

Comment: @Basj I don't know if `ssl` vs. `tls` makes a difference really, but TLS is the current version of the protocol, so should be preferred both in naming and versioning.

Comment: @Basj What kind of connection a browser has to your server is irrelevant and nobody knows that. You're opening a socket from a PHP program to Paypal, you may as well be doing that directly from the command line without any "HTTP" connection involved at all.

Comment: As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995008/1422096) (this problem gave me headaches ;)), `tls://` was creating problems, whereas `ssl://` worked!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you abandon fsocket in favour of curl. Its a lot more reliable (I think). Ive just updated my curl component within my ipn.php to be compliant with Paypals requirements of HTTP1/1 and TLS1.2 (sslversion=6)
The code is

```
//NOW SEND IT ALL BACK TO PAYPAL AS CONFIRMATION//
// USING CURL AS PHP FSOCKOPEN IS LESS RELIABLE //
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$paypal_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It works fine

Comment: Thank you. Why is `curl` more reliable than `fsockopen`? (I ask this because I think my IPN has worked flawlessly with hundreds of calls to fsockopen every year).

Comment: fsockopen merely opens a socket and away you go with your comms. Anything else has to be added. Curl on the other hand is PHPs HTTP (and HTTPS) comms manager. Using HTTPS, Curl is the complete package, something fsockopen cant do. If you have fsockopen working on your server, then maybe stick with it, but expect some issues if you update your server, the other ends(s) update there servers or HTTPS becomes a requirement, as is now the case with Paypal now insisting HTTP1/1 and TLS 1.2, something that fsock will relly struggle with

Comment: Could you post @gri2a a full example of IPN php using curl, showing also the `$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';` and validation (with fsockopen I used   `while (!feof($fp))
  {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
`? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comments about Curl, Paypal developers have supplied several sets of source code for IPN. They supply C++, Python, ASP, PHP, and a whole bunch more. You will find them on github. All of the PHP solutions use Curl. Even though some of the uploads are a few years old they must have known that Paypal would update their full comms (for IPN) to HTTPS.
Even with some of the older packages, a simple adding of 1 line of code to set SSL version to 6 and the old codes are good to go for Paypals new requirements

Answer (score 2):

The link at https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples is a compilation of codes in Python, Ruby, Perl, Asp and a few others including PHP.
A direct link to the PHP component is at https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php
This is the one I use because its already HTTP1/1 and TLS1.2 "ready" and therefore ticks all the boxes for Paypal's new security compliance.
There area few other github samples, some over 6 years old, but this is the most up to date

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably also change that `HTTP/1.0` to `HTTP/1.1` now, as per PayPal's latest requirements. So that's:

```
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to deceze's answer, PayPal's update now requires you to use `ipnpb.paypal.com`

Try using this code instead.

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
```

Comment: Thanks @FluxCoder. Can you add a link to source (Paypal's update), or cite it here, it would be useful for future reference?