# PayPal IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying to update my PayPal IPN, and I seem to be stuck. I would appreciate some help if someone could spare there time. As the title says, the Postback needs to be updated to HTTPS.

```
    $demo = false;
    $url = 'www.paypal.com';

    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

I have tried the following: 
changing the $url to have tls:// and ssl:// in from of www.PayPal.com & www.ipnpb.paypal.com

I have also changed the port to 443 in `$fp`.

When I had tried ipnpb.paypal.com I just got stuck in an infinite loading loop.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTPS URL needs to start with `https://`.

Not `tls://` or `ssl://`, which are figments of your imagination.

It also needs to be connected to port 443, and to follow the appropriate redirects.

Comment: When I changed the port to 443 it did not work properly. As for your comment on tls and ssl it was referenced in this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465835/paypal-ipn-verification-postback-with-https

Comment: 'If OpenSSL is installed'. I don't see that mentioned in your question.

Comment: OpenSSL is definitely installed.